# Trying to increase code coverage for a trigger that deletes events

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage, code, delete

So I'm trying to write a test class to meet code coverage requirements to push up this trigger:

```
trigger DeleteEventsOnCancellation on Case (after update) {
    for(Case c : system.trigger.new){
        if(c.Status == 'Cancelled')
        {
            List<Event> events = [SELECT ID FROM Event WHERE WhatID = :c.ID];
            delete events;

        }
    }


}
```

I'm only reaching 50% coverage with this test class and am stuck on how to get that up to 100%. The delete events call is what is being marked as uncovered. Here's the test class:

```
@isTest
public class testDeleteEventsOnCancellation {

    static testMethod void testEventDeletion(){

         Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'];

        User u = new User();
        u.FirstName = 'Test';
        u.LastName = 'User2';
...
        insert u;

        User u2 = new User();
        u2.FirstName = 'test';
        u2.LastName = 'User';
...
        insert u2;

        Account a = new Account();
        a.Name = 'Test Account';
        insert a;

        Case c = new Case();
        c.AccountId = a.Id;
        c.Status = 'New';
        c.Origin = 'Email';
        c.RecordTypeId = Case.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Work Order').getRecordTypeId();
        insert c;

        Event e = new Event();
        e.WhatId=c.Id;
         e.StartDateTime=datetime.now();
        e.EndDateTime=datetime.now();
        insert e;
                Event e2 = new Event();
        e2.WhatId=c.Id;
         e2.StartDateTime=datetime.now();
        e2.EndDateTime=datetime.now();
        insert e2;

        test.startTest();
        c.Status= '9-Cancelled';
        update c;
        test.stopTest();

        List<Event> events = [SELECT ID,IsDeleted FROM Event WHERE WhatID = :c.ID];
        for(Event ev:events){
            system.assertequals(ev.IsDeleted,true);
        }

    }


}
```

Is there something I need to do differently to cover the delete method?

Comment: Your trigger checks for `status` value `Cancelled` and that you are setting this value in your test class as `9-Cancelled`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

In your trigger if block ,you are checking if case is canceled.

```
if(c.Status == 'Cancelled')
```

and in your test class you are setting it as `9-Cancelled` and as `Cancelled` is not equal to `9-Cancelled` , its not entering the block.

You can fix it by fixing the case status in test class.

```
    test.startTest();
    c.Status= 'Cancelled';
    update c;
    test.stopTest()
```

Answer (score 3):

At least with the code you have now, your test class is not covering it correctly.

You have the following in your trigger:

```
if(c.Status == 'Cancelled')
```

And that you are it as below in your test class:

```
 c.Status= '9-Cancelled';
```

---

To get to the condition thus covering your code, you should set the status value to `Cancelled` in your test class as:

```
c.Status= 'Cancelled';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually increase your code coverage simply by optimizing your code. Here's a new version of the trigger:

```
trigger DeleteEventsOnCancellation on Case (after update) {
    delete [SELECT Id FROM Task WHERE WhatId IN (SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE Id = :Trigger.new AND Status='Cancelled')];
}
```

You will, of course, need to verify that the tasks where successfully deleted, so make sure you query back and assert. Also, as the other answers state, '9-Cancelled' is not the same as 'Cancelled'.

Also, in your original code, be aware that you have a DML in a loop, which could break in large updates. You should strive to write unit tests that test **at least 200** records to make sure you're not hitting governor limits.